# Docker (Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified) even after setting the password and db in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: javascript, docker, electron

Still running into an error when connecting my postgres db to Docker. The Error is Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified. When I open up the app through electron, the dev tools gives me an error that the database does not exists. I've tried force removing and rebuilding the image. Is there a step I'm missing to solve this?

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
    volumes:
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
      - ./docketeerdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
volumes:
  schema: {}
  docketeerdb: {}
```

Comment: As you've shown it, there is an extra space in the `POSTGRES_DB= db` line; does deleting this space make a difference?  (The `volumes:` you show at the end aren't used, and you shouldn't normally need to set `container_name:` either.)

Comment: Thanks for responding David, unfortunately it still give me the same error.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?  From another container, or from outside Docker; if from outside Docker, from the same host or from elsewhere?

Comment: Connecting through another container.